# DBeaver list of script (F3) is empty after profile migration to new laptop

Tags: dbeaver

I have moved my DBeaver settings from old laptop to new one, ie. I found the `workspace6` folder and copied everything into new laptop including the `Scripts` folder.

After I started the DBeaver on new laptop I saw all the connections BUT when I open some connection and hit `F3` to `Open SQL Script` all I found is empty list.

To make sure everything is located correctly I created new script and saved it using Ctrl+S to see where it will be stored. Then I found the new script in the same folder as the other scripts that are "invisible". So the path is correct and is readable/writable by DBeaver.

> Is there a way how to migrate the binding/ownership of connection to the existing scripts?

Note I want to avoid manual binding aka script-by-script since I have 10+ connections with 100+ scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I take opposite approach to migrate the DBeaver from old laptop to new one, ie. not doing it via copying the workspace but to use Export/Import feature from GUI.

**Clearing the workspace**

You may skip this step. I did it not to mess up my already partly migrated settings with new settings to be imported I decided to clear the DBeaver workspace first, i.e. I found the workspace location within the DBeaver settings and manually deleted the General folder in there. The path to the workspace can be found in `Preferences > General > Workspace`

**Old laptop**

- **Export**

  - open DBeaver menu `File > Export`
  - choose export wizard `DBeaver > Project`
  - select project to be exported `[x] General`
  - set the `output file name` and `directory`
  - click `Finish`
  - This will create a file named `General-yyymmdd.dbp`

**New laptop**

- **Import**

  - open DBeaver menu `File > Import`
  - choose Import wizard `DBeaver > Project`
  - select the file to import and select the project to be imported `[x] General`
  - click `Finish`
- **Set active project**

  - In case of using multiple Projects set one active
  - open DBeaver menu `Window > Show view > Projects`
  - right click the Project and set `Set Active Project`
- **Delete project**

  - only in case you have obsolete project and need to delete them. 
    Only inactive projects can be deleted! 
    To make the project inactive may need to set as an active project any other project and then you will be able to delete the inactive project
  - open DBeaver menu `Window > Show view > Projects`
  - right click the Project and select `Delete`
  - un/check the option `Delete project content on disk`

**Restart the DBeaver**

- might not be needed but I just want to make sure it rereads all the settings.

**Solved**

Now I can see all the `Connections`, `Diagrams`, `Bookmarks`, and `Scripts` in `Window > Show view > Project Explorer` AND all the scripts related to each connection after pressing the <kbd>F3</kbd> button.